# Authentication failed for 'github.com/....' jenkins

Tags: git, authentication, github, jenkins

I am trying to log in to GitHub from Jenkins in order to run a job and then commit and push it to GitHub.

I've tried [the steps in the first comment of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559456/configuring-jenkins-with-github-authorization) and it does not work for me: It keeps saying that the authentication failed, even though I already set everything on the Git Auth plugin.

This is the [jenkins console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZaZb.png):

[image: error]

Comment: Hi ccaldito! Welcome :) Formatted code included in the question would be much easier for others to see and help you with your issue; not all users will click on the link to the image! I would recommend editing your Question to include this. [This page has a helpful guide to formatting your code/error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please use SSH key to checkout or push in github. Follow [this]( http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/y3ck/integrating-jenkins-with-github-over-ssh) article to get it setup.

Answer (score 1):

> although i already set everything on the git auth plugin

Make sure that what you "have set" involves using a [PAT (Personnal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) as password.

Then the connection would work, since GitHub no longer use user account password directly.